# How to pass post parameters in laravel from the route to the controller?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm doing this query in the payment controller and i need to get a post request from the route.

Controller:

```
class PaymentController extends Controller 
{
    public function apiPaymentByUserId($date_from, $date_to) { 


        $payments = DB::table("casefiles, payments")
            ->select("payments.*")
            ->where("casefiles.id", "=", 'payments.casefile_id')
            ->where("casefiles.user_id", "=", Auth::id())
            ->where("payments.created_at", ">=", $data_from)
            ->where("payments.updated_at", "<=", $data_to)
            ->get();

            
            return response()->json([ 
                'success' => true, 
                'response' => $payments 
            ]);
    
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/payments/{date_from}/{date_to}', 'Api\PaymentController@apiPaymentByUserId');
```

How to pass multiple parameters in this post route? Thank you

Comment: you  will direct receive post param in `request` , no need to pass in route

Comment: If there's a need to do so depends on the route spec. Sometimes it makes sense to have both.

Comment: rename $data_from to $date_from 
& 
$data_to to $date_to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For post request no need to pass param in url .You will get in request

So route will be

```php
Route::post('/payments', 'Api\PaymentController@apiPaymentByUserId');
```

and controller method

```php
public function apiPaymentByUserId(Request $request) 
{ 
    $date_from = $request->date_from;
    $date_to = $request->date_to;
}
```

Comment: It would be even better to use get for the method since it just loads data (considering the api design is restful).

Comment: For **POST** request no need to pass *param* in url . Send the Dates as FORM values sent via POST method along with the rest of the FORM values (if any, you're already POSTing in the FORM). You will get all FORM values sent via POST method in ***Request $request*** object instance, passed in ***Controller/Method***.

So route will be:

```php
Route::post('/payments', 'Api\PaymentController@apiPaymentByUserId');
```
and controller method:
 
```php
public function apiPaymentByUserId(Request $request) 
{ 
    $date_from = $request->date_from;
    $date_to = $request->date_to;
}
```

Comment: Improved grammatical omissions like a SPACE was missed before "You will get.....", and overall understanding for readers what we are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to change your url, try this in your controller `apiPaymentByUserId()` method, inject the Request object along with the other path variables like like:

```
public function apiPaymentByUserId(Illuminate\Http\Request $request, $date_from, $date_to) { 
      // ... you can access the request body with the methods available in $request object depending on your needs.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For **POST** request no need to pass *param* in url . Send the Dates as FORM values sent via POST method along with the rest of the FORM values (if any, you're already POSTing in the FORM). You will get all FORM values sent via POST method in ***Request $request*** object instance, passed in ***Controller/Method***.

So route will be:

```php
Route::post('/payments', 'Api\PaymentController@apiPaymentByUserId');
```

and controller method:

```php
public function apiPaymentByUserId(Request $request) 
{ 
    $date_from = $request->date_from;
    $date_to = $request->date_to;
}
```

Comment: @Aogiri14 please upvote my answer revision as i was trying to update the selected answer, i was getting _**UPDATE/EDIT QUEUE IS FULL. TRY AGAIN LATER**_.